# Error - required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php) index.php line 22 in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on Laravel 5.2 framework and run first time project

When i run root link display error:

```
Warning: require(/home/ubuntu/workspace/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php on line 22 Call Stack: 0.0028 236248 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:0 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/ubuntu/workspace/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php on line 22 Call Stack: 0.0028 236248 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:0
```

Before i call composer install

Its my **application/.htpaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

     # Handle Front Controller...
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
     RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

**application/index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**EDIT:**

I replaced in index.php to

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

But display error:

```
Warning: require(/home/ubuntu/workspace/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php on line 22 Call Stack: 0.0004 233376 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:0 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/ubuntu/workspace/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php on line 22 Call Stack: 0.0004 233376 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:0
```

I have folder vendor in root directory. How me solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Run this commands in terminal:
`php artisan clear-compiled` ,
`composer install` ,
`composer update` ,
`composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: The autoload file is located in the `vendor` folder. Try `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` instead.

Comment: i changed to  __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'. Error:    Failed opening required '/home/ubuntu/workspace/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')

Comment: What is your php version? I'm getting this error when I used PHP < 5.5.9

Comment: you will probably find your solution by following the steps here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but bellow command over the composer sort out everything for me.

`composer update --no-scripts`

Sometimes when you run: `composer install` you got that error too, so the best option is first to run: `composer install --no-scripts` and then run composer install normally.

Answer (score 2):

`__DIR__` is an absolute path to the directory of the script that you're running.

Get a terminal and `cd` to the directory where this script lives. From there, use `ls` together with paths such as up one directory (`../`) and the tab-based autocompletion to find the path that you need to use to locate the `autoload.php` from your index script.

If you get a result like this:

```
$ ls ../public/index.php
ls: cannot access ../public/index.php: No such file or directory
```

Then you know the file doesn't exist at the path specified.

I feel it's better to answer this question by telling you how to find it rather than guessing at where it should be.

Comment: thank you. I delete one /../. Load without this error, but now display `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this error here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the issue in your composer.json because i also had the same.

Please replace your whole "scripts" object in composer.json with this..

```
"scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
```

Now try to run composer install if not works then composer update.